# Nodejs - Create modules from string with the npm package 'module'

Tags: node.js

I want to load a custom module using the npm package 'module', to be able to require it like any other local folder that exports something.

I cannot find any documentation on the use of the package https://www.npmjs.com/package/module

I tried to use it without any documentation on it, but i simply cannot as i dont understand how you use it.

````
    let myFunction = module.wrap(`module.exports = () => console.log("hej")`);```
````

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, I've never read documentation about this but I've been using Node.js for years so I'll explain how I import modules. Given a project that has the files app.js and mod1.js and the subfolder utils with the file mod2.js, you could do something like this:

prj/mod1.js

```
    module.exports = {
        test: "testing"
    }
```

prj/utils/mod2.js

```
    module.exports = () => {
        console.log("testing");
    }
```

prj/app.js

```
    var mod1 = require("mod1"),
        mod2 = require("utils/mod2");

    console.log(mod1.test);
    mod2();
```

Comment: That doesn't answer my question, please read it all the way through.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to create a module of your own to be able to use it at multiple places within your project ( correct me if I am wrong).

SO you can do that like :
In utils/custom.js

```
 module.exports = {
    logThis: "Hi"
}
```

OR

```
var a={ 
 logThis:function (){
  console.log('HI')
}
module.exports=a;
```

And then in the file where you want to access this :
 In app.js

```
let custom=require('./utils/custom.js')
```

Comment: Yes, and i know how to create modules.
I want to create a "session" module that isnt local, but can be put in a fake directory, and load it from there like it's a local file